# get an exact JPanel registered to JPanel with CardLayout setted

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I register to a cardPanel object 3 JPanel.

```
JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

cardPanel.add(viewPerf, "Performances");
cardPanel.add(viewFaults, "Faults");
cardPanel.add(viewGraph, "Throughput Graph");
```

I would obtain exactly one JPanel.how can I do this operation?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I have three jpanel registered to jpanel cardpanel and I would get viewGraph panel.how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show a particular component in a `CardLayout`, use the `CardLayout#show(String)` method, passing the name you gave the component when you added it:

```
((CardLayout)cardPanel.getLayout()).show("Throughput Graph");
```

Alternatively, you can save the layout when you create it:

```
CardLayout cardPanelLayout = new CardLayout();
cardPanel.setLayout(cardPanelLayout);
...
cardPanelLayout.show("Throughput Graph");
```

Edit: To get a reference to the currently visible component, I believe you can do this:

```
Component visibleComp = null;
for (Component comp : cardPanel.getComponents()) {
  if (comp.isVisible()) {
    visibleComp = comp;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't what I was looking for...the method show is void so I didn't get anything